# Several foundation reveal modals need different backgrounds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I have 2 Foundation reveal modals on one page. Independently they work fine except I need the background for one to be black and the other white. Unfortunately, the reveal modals use one common background by default (.reveal-modal-bg). How can I achieve different styling for this background or give each modal its unique background? Here's my call on the page:

```
<script>
$(document).foundation('reveal', 
{
animation: 'fade',
animation_speed: 200,
close_on_background_click: true,
dismiss_modal_class: 'close-reveal-modal',
multiple_opened: false,
bg_class: 'reveal-modal-bg',
root_element: 'body',
on_ajax_error: $.noop,
bg : $('.reveal-modal-bg'),
css : {
open : {
  'opacity': 0,
  'visibility': 'visible',
  'display': 'block',
  'transition': 'visibility 0s linear 0.2s, opacity 0.2s linear'
},
close : {
  'opacity': 1,
  'visibility': 'hidden',
  'display': 'none',
  'transition-delay': '0s'
}
}
});
</script>
```

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to handle this directly in CSS. You can do this by appending an additional class to the modals in question and setting the background color.

Comment: The common background is created dynamically by the foundation jquery, and is the parent of all modals on the page, so i'm not quite sure how that would work... Thanks for your answer.